# Curl equivalent of wget --user --password

Tags: curl, wget

I want to use curl to get the web contents of the page instead of wget. I need to pass the credentials..

`wget --user=<user> --ask-password <url>`  is working just fine.

How can I perform the same operation using curl?

I tried `curl -u <user> <url>`

But looks like it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Passing user and pass is a bad idea, It's safer to do like this

```
curl --netrc-file my-password-file http://foo.com
```

The format of the password file is like below.

```
machine <foo.com> login <username> password <password>
```

This keeps the password out of the process listing and command history

//Not recommended way because of security risk

```
curl -u username:password  {{ http://www.foo.com }} -O
```

Comment: 1. curl clears the -u string from ps outputs on most platforms and 2. *please* remove the `-X GET`...